# How to color button in red?

Tags: rebol, red

I tried this code snippet like in rebol:

```
View [button "colored" 100.0.0]
```

but the button is still in grey.

Comment: In Red buttons created using OS native widgets and button color is not supported yet. It works on Rebol because Rebol's buttons are not native OS buttons.
And on Windows background color on buttons supported only for owner-drawn buttons (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775943(v=vs.85).aspx)
So Red team needs to find a cross platform solution for Red, but they have higher priority tasks.

Comment: @endo64 ok thanks.

Comment: Should I put my comment as an answer? :) I thought someone could provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Such feature is not supported yet when using native button widget. Though, you can create a custom button easily using the versatile `base` face type:

```
view [
    base red
        on-down [face/color: face/color / 2]
        on-up   [face/color: face/color * 2]
]
```

You can also create a new custom style out of that (requires at least Red autobuild from master branch from Jan 3rd, 2019):

```
view [
    style but: base
        on-down [face/color: face/color / 2 do-actor face event 'click]
        on-up   [face/color: face/color * 2]

    but "Say hi!" red on-click [print "hi"]
]
```